# Buttons flicker despite Application.ScreenUpdating = False?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class that I call at the beginning of some subs:

```
Private bSattOmdomenProtected As Boolean
Private bSkapaOmdomeslistorProtected As Boolean


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Cursor = xlWait


    'Protection
    bSattOmdomenProtected = wSattOmdomen.ProtectContents
    bSkapaOmdomeslistorProtected = wSkapaOmdomeslistor.ProtectContents
    wSattOmdomen.Unprotect
    wSkapaOmdomeslistor.Unprotect
    'End protection

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()


    'Protection
    If bSattOmdomenProtected Then
        wSattOmdomen.Protect AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True 'AllowFormattingCells:=True , UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End If
    If bSkapaOmdomeslistorProtected Then
        wSkapaOmdomeslistor.Protect AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True 'AllowFormattingCells:=True,, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End If
    'End protection

    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Example of how I call the class:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim general As New cGeneralLines
    Set general = New cGeneralLines

    'Code
End Sub
```

I find this to work well for setting application states. But since I added the code labeled Protection in the class, all buttons in my worksheets flicker, even though I have set Application.ScreenUpdating = False.

The specific line that causes the flicker seems to be when I try to change the protection settings of another sheet than the active one.

Why is this? How can I have the functionality of the sheet protection code but avoid getting flickering buttons?

Comment: Have you tried putting `DoEvents` before that line?

Comment: Ive never come accross DoEvents before. Ill try it later. What do we hope to accomplish with it?

Comment: From Microsoft's website: "The DoEvents function surrenders execution of the macro so that the operating system can process other events." I've used it in the past to clear up issues with flickering, but I'm not overly knowledgeable as to what exactly it is doing.

Comment: Did this solve your issue?

Comment: No. I figured out later that the flicker happens because my code has switched sheed during execution. Even though Excel is back on the starting sheet before application.screenupdating is set to true again, buttons and some other things on the sheet will redraw. I found out that this is what was happening, but didn't find out any way to surpress that behavior.

Comment: There are some workarounds, but I doubt that this is a good solution: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/unprotect-causing-objects-to-flicker-hide.1029435/