# Command button and other objects not visible while macro runs

Tags: vba, excel

I have some buttons and other objects (a picture, group box, labels, etc) on my sheet.

I have a very long and complex macro that executes from one of these buttons. The code is calculations and other automation but nothing alters appearance of or interacts with these objects. 
Due to its size, sensitivity and complexity I cannot post the code.

My problem is while this code is running, all of these objects disappear from the sheet, and become visible again when the macro is complete.

Doing some research on similar issues there are various settings when you right click on the object > Format Control, like ticking "Automatic Size", but I have had an experiment with this and other settings and nothing has worked.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

EDIT: I believe I have the same problem as the person in this question:
[Buttons flicker despite Application.ScreenUpdating = False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196341/buttons-flicker-despite-application-screenupdating-false)

I am also using `.unprotect` to unlock another sheet as part of my sub.
The `doevents` mentioned in the comments for this question does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some of the lines below in your code:

```
ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Those line could deactivate the controls.